# Terse filling of the Cayley table

Tags: group-theory, cayley-table

> Given a group of order $n$, what are the least number of elements to specify on the Cayley table to specify a group?

**Example**

Consider this $Z_4$ group table for example:

[image]

Due to abelian-ness I can hide these elements and still lose no information:

[image]

Furthermore, I just need one slot filled to know the action of identity on everything else. So, I can shade these terms out as well:

[image]

Further more I can shade darken out one element on the second row:

[image]

This is because I know that purply shaded element must be '1' only as identity acts on it, and I also know that each row must have one identity.

---

Taking assumptions on the nature of Group will quickly reduce the upper bound of elements needed to be specified.

Is there any algorithm to strike out maximum number of slots in the cayley table?

If the group is abelian, as shown, we can quickly just strike elements above or below main diagonal.

Comment: I don't think you are interpreting the question correctly. In particular, "we should begin by specifying the identity" seems like a non sequitur to me. I understand the question essentially as saying: how many entries do you need to fill out in the Cayley table before the whole table is completely forced, given that you know you have a group? There is no requirement that the "outer edges" must correspond to the identity...

Comment: Your interpretation is right. I am keeping identity as last element in row of elements. @arturo

Comment: Do I understand correctly that to uniquely assign the group $S_3=\operatorname{gr}(a,b\mid a^2=b^2=(ab)^3=e)$ in the Cayley table, it is sufficient to fill $6$ places:
$$
(e,e),=e\ (a,a)=e,\ (b,b)=e,\ (a,b)=ab,\ (ab,ab)=(ab)^2,\ (ab,(ab)^2)=e?
$$

Comment: Wdym by 'in = e'? @kabenyuk

Comment: You're assuming form of one element (ab)^3 soo I didn't have that in mind.

Comment: It could be like this.  These are the $6$ values that unambiguously continue up to the Cayley table of a group isomorphic to $S_3$: 
$$
T(1,1)=1,\ T(2,2)=1,\ T(3,3)=1,\ T(2,3)=4,\ T(4,4)=5,\ T(4,5)=1.
$$
Or am I misunderstanding you?

Comment: I don't understand your notation $T( ,)$ , is there a name for it so I can look it up @kabenyuk

Comment: T is a Cayley table of a group of the order of $6$.

What I'm trying to get at is the idea that filling in a very small number of places in the Calley table is enough to set a group. 

However, it is possible that I misunderstood your question, so I am trying to clarify it.

Comment: You are exactly right @kabenyuk. It's just first I've seen  notation like that

Comment: I've edited the question @ArturoMagidin

Comment: @kabenyuk please check again

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your example.
I argue that you can only keep three elements in the Cayley table - this
$$
T(0,0),T(1,1), T(1,2).
$$
The remaining elements of this table can be reconstructed by knowing the size of the table and it's three values.

For example, $T(2,2)\neq3$, $T(2,2)\neq2$, and $T(2,2)\neq1$. The first two are obvious. If $T(2,2)=1$, then $1+1+1+1=1$, i.e. $1+1+1=0$ and $T(1,2)=0$. Contradiction.

Comment: How did you get that both $1+1+1+1=1$ and $1+1+1+1=0$?

Comment: This is a typo, my apologies. I corrected my answer.